# Why are initial connections always slower

Tags: http, tcp, web, udp

I first noticed this when using Insomnia (HTTP clients) to test some of my API endpoints.

The first request I make to my API server (and others) is always 100ms+ but sequential requests are always super quick latency wise.

[image: First Request Image]

[image: Second Request Image]

How is this possible? I tried sending random data each request and this is still happening. I also recently heard of QUIC protocol by Google which is meant to reduce handshake request round trips from **~3** to **0** for common servers. This makes a lot of sense to what is happening but QUIC is not even deployed web-wide yet.

Comment: Is DNS involved?

Comment: Haha. That's it then. But why does DNS take 100ms+??

Comment: It really depends on your setup. But one possible explanation (taking DNS into account) would be that your client doesn't have a cached entry for that server. So before being able to make a request it would need to do a DNS lookup in order to know which server to connect to. The server and your client may also support keep alive so maybe the connection isn't closed between requests.

Comment: QUIC can reduce latencies, but not to zero. It works by creating it's own mechanism which behaves somewhat similar to tcp by using udp, and overcoming some of the limits in the tcp protocol. It's not magic though.

Comment: It might also be session management on the remote endpoint. The first time you connect it’s allocating resources to the connection and starting up threads. After that you’re just reusing the same resources until they timeout and are freed.

Comment: If you're using HTTPS, it might be caching the TLS session, which can save a lot of time during connection setup.  It may also just be keeping the connection open after the first request (which of course eliminates the connection setup time).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Is this normal behavior for normal HTTP APIs w/ vanilla HTTP clients? e.g. Express/Hapi with Postman.

Comment: @Kirk122 It's not 'normal', but it's also not 'not normal', it really just depends on the framework.  If you're using HTTP/2 for example, you're almost guaranteed to be pipelining requests (it's an implicit part of HTTP/2).  If you're using HTTP/1.0 (or 0.9), you inherently aren't pipelining.  For HTTP/1.1, it ends up being dependent on the server configuration and the application framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As other mentioned in the comments to your initial post that it could be DNS, which is a very reasonable idea as to the cause of the delay.

However, there is no way for us to know the actual answer to your question.  We dont know what is going on with *your* setup, nor can we, without access.

There is a tool you can use to diagnose the problem.  [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) is an excellent tool, in which I can highly recommend.  It can help diagnose web based problems.  I suggest you give it a shot.